# How to hide elements on another page twig (symphony)

Tags: html, css, twig

So I have an index page with products and when clicked it goes on another page with the prodcut itself ( i am extending the app.twig on the product page) and it takes all the elements from there to the product page. My question is there anyway to hide elements on another page if you have extended another page ?

Comment: Please include some code to make your question clear.

Comment: I have discovered the answer thank you for looking over my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have discovered that if I create blocks than I call them in the page i dont want them empty it will erase them.